# How to setup grunt-babel to transpile an entire directory

Tags: gruntjs, babeljs

So I have this in my gruntfile:

```
gruntConfig.babel = {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                "dist/server.js": "src/*.js"
            }
        }
    };
```

This correctly transpiles all the js files in src, but it overwrites dist/server.js every time.

This must be really simple, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it write to different output files, one for each sourcefile.

Comment: This is super annoying and obviously not something anyone would ever want. And doesn't it go against the default Grunt behavior? Maybe I'm stupid but according to the Grunt docs the above should result in a concatenated file, which is what I'm struggling to achieve at the moment.

Comment: a minor correction: afaik, this will not "transpile all the js files in src", it will stop after the first one.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's can be achieved by using [dynamic files mapping](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically).

For your case config will look like this:

```
gruntConfig.babel = {
    options: {
        sourceMap: true
    },
    dist: {
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'src/',
                src: ['*.js'],
                dest: 'dist/'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Doesn't this preserver the structure of `src/`, rather than concatenating into `dist/`?

Comment: "Preserve" not "preserver" . . . thanks stack overflow for disallowing comment edits after 5 minutes.

Comment: I forgive you @tandrewnichols